# Portfolio Optimization via Entropy Pooling in R (Meucci)

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, entropy-pooling

does anybody have experience with the Entropy Pooling Approach by Meucci in R?

I am currently trying to do a portfolio optimization with Stocks & Bonds, where a 101 example would be very helpful. The published examples (demos in Meucci package & one example with the edhec-Data) unfortunately did not help me.

I would like to use stock prices, respectively returns as priori. Do i have to fit the data? For example as multivariate skewed t-distribution? and how can i use the distribution for the EntropyProg Function? Second Question: what package do you use for the following optimization of the posterior?

I am very grateful for every advice or help.

Regards.

Comment: Could you list some of the examples and explain why they are not helpful? It will help others help to help you.

Comment: @BobJansen i did try the demos of the Meucci Package and some example with the edhec data. Do you have some other good examples? Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with entropy pooling. Hopefully someone else comes along to help you.

Comment: @BobJansen thanks anyway!

Comment: Please don't make small edits just to put your question on top of the page.

Comment: Hi: I don't have any experience with those topics either. But, the help file on the cran page of the Meucci package, which is a pdf  file, will usually contain references to the approaches used in the Meucci package.

Comment: @markleeds thx Mark. Can you pls provide me with a link? :)

Comment: Hi: It looks like it's not on cran but you can email the maintainer of the package and ask if there is a pdf for the package. https://rdrr.io/github/R-Finance/Meucci/#vignettes

Comment: @puRe22 what is entropy pooling? is it related to Shannon entropy

Comment: @develarist No, i don't think so. It's a specific method for portfolio optimization, where you can incorporate your individual opinion an an assets as so-called view. Afterwards the market prior distribution is blended with the investors views to retrieve a posterior distribution for corresponding portfolio optimization.